# OroCommerce with Amazon MQ

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

I'm trying to find information about Amazon MQ on OroCommerce but found nothing solid. Is it possible to use Amazon MQ intend of RabbitMQ for out of the box OroCommerce? Does Oro have some additional bundles for it? Are there some risks to use them?

Answer (score 0):

Officially it's not supported.

Pay attention that RabbitMQ is available only in an Enterprise Edition of the OroCommerce application. In the Community Edition, the DBAL transport is used.

See https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/#concepts